# Updating the contents of a JTextField so that it keeps refreshing everything?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, concurrency

I have this code to tell me if a port is open or not(available func). And I call that function in my GUI program like this:

```
String newavail = "" + available(9002) ;


JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Is Port 9002(GWT Pet Store) available? \n" + newavail);
```

But if I close the port outside of the running GUI it doesn't reflect this change right away. I read that you can use a revalidate() command, but how do you use that?

Comment: Your main problem is not Swing; you have to find a way to get notified when port 9002 availability is changing; you would probably have to create a `Thread` that periodically checks the availability of that port, then update the GUI (with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`) if availability has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the port is closed outside the Event Dispatch Thread, you should use [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) to set the text of the `JTextField` instance to reflect the availability status change.

---

```
// we're outside the EDT
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // modify Swing component here
    }
});
```

Comment: This is interesting - so there's a separate SwingUtilities class, that's cool. I'm on it, Thank You,

Comment: @Adel, And in particular, use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). See edit!